# 感じも演出しておいた meaning

Tags: meaning

> **後はちょっと弱みを握られてる感じも演出しておいたかな。**

I read the meaning of **演出** are: 1. **production** (e.g. play); **direction**; 2. **Staging** (theatre)​

Is it correct to interpret **感じも演出** as **being led by emotion**?

Thank you in advance for the guidance.

Comment: 〜（弱みを握られてる感じ）も演出して〜

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand. Please kindly explain it in English, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Amanda Judging by how you phrased the question, you seem to have parsed the sentence as 感じも演出 being a single unit, but actually the verb is 演出する and its object is not 感じ, but rather is the entirety of ちょっと弱みを握られてる感じ. ... is what macraf was trying to point out I think. :)

Answer (score 2):

感じ doesn't mean "emotion" but "impression". So 弱みを握られてる感じ means " impressions that someone has something on (the person)"

弱みを握られてる感じを演出する means "I direct impressions that someone has something on (the person)"